# Open a file from the same package

Tags: java

I want to open help.chm file when click on the help button. At present , it is opened from the desktop when click help button. I copied and paste the file in one of the packages in my project. Is there a way to open this file from this package?

This is what I did to open the file from desktop

```
private void helpActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)    
{                                            
    try
    {


         Runtime.getRuntime().exec("hh.exe C:/Users/toshiba/Desktop/help2.chm");
    }    
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }            
}
```

Comment: You need to be more specific if you want answers that will solve your problem. From the way you have written your question, I am tempted to state the obvious. Have you tried specifying the absolute path to the chm file? For instance, if your file is in a package com.abc on drive C, have you tried specifying the path as C:\com\abc?

Comment: @bot Sorry if i wasn't specific. Yes i tried to use the absolute path.but the point of my question is if i moved the jar file to another place , then the file won't open.

Comment: `help2.chm` will most likely be an [tag:embedded-resource] by the time this is deployed, and I doubt the resource will be accessible to `hh.exe`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`getResourceAsStream(String name)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) or `getResources(String name)` and provide the package name and resource name separated and prefixed by '/'.

For example if the resource is in the package Test:

> /Test/help.chm:

Inside the class which you want to access the resource from you'd do (`getResourceAsStream(String name)`):

```
InputStream is=getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Test/help.chm");
```

or using `getResources(String name)`:

```
URL file=getClass().getResource("/Test/help.chm");
```

for further help have a look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/lang/resources.html) great tutorial.

Comment: @CalmSea yes have a look at [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)

Answer (score 2):

if your file is inside jar package you could get url in this way:

```
URL resource = getClass().getResource("yourFile.chm");
System.out.println("URL to resource: " + resource );
```

or you can try something like:

```
//it return the relative path 

ResourcesLoader.class.getClassLoader().getResource("package1/resources/repository/yourFile.chm").toString(); // if file is inside package
```